# DML result refresh

Tags: visualforce, dml

When I click button, method's `setToApprove()` action is beginning.

But first lines of method when `terf_mr_status='approved'` and `terf_mr_approveddate=TODAY_VALUE` doesn't appears inside of generated pdf attachment. these updated fields only appears after method's ending.

How to fix it? Thank you!

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public PageReference setToApprove() {

    //  update MR fields:

    MR.TERF_MR_Status__c = 'Approved';
    DateTime d = Date.Today().addDays(1) ;
    MR.TERF_MR_ApproveDate__c = d.format('dd.MM.yyyy');
    update MR;

    //  convert vf-page to attachment:
    PageReference pdf = Page.TERF_Print;
    pdf.getParameters().put('id', MR.Id);
    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    Blob body;
    try {
        body = pdf.getContent();
    } catch (VisualforceException e) {
        body = Blob.valueOf('Error: ' + e);
    }

    attach.Body = body;
    attach.Name = 'DopForm-' + mr.TERF_MR_EmployeeFullname__c + '-' + mr.TERF_MR_year__c + '-' + mr.TERF_MR_monthNumber__c + ', ' + d.format('dd.MM.yyyy') + '.pdf';
    attach.IsPrivate = false;
    attach.ParentId = MR.Id;
    insert attach;

    //  update URL field
    MR.TERF_MR_AttachmentURL__c = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + attach.Id;
    upsert MR;

    //  update page 
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/TERF_EditMR');
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id', report.Id);
    return pageRef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CONTROLLER**

I put lines of attachment creation into another method createAttachment(); and run it "onComplete":

**VF PAGE**

```
<apex:actionFunction name="generatePDF" action="{!createAttachment}"></apex:actionFunction>

<apex:commandbutton value="Approve" action="{!setToApprove}" onComplete="generatePDF();">
```